# npm run watch crashes after any change in vue or js files: compileTemplate now requires the `id` option.`

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, node-modules, laravel-mix

[image]

Both npm run dev and prod works properly, however when I try to run watch, and change files, npm run watch throws an error and crashes.

Using laravel mix with TS, webpack mix params:

```
 .webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/] },
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx", ".vue", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    },
})
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution was to add transpileOnly:true to the options on you webpack.mix.js.

All credits go to: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/wabpack-cli-error-on-reload-watch

Answer (score 0):

I was using a mix of vanilla Javascript and Typescript in my Vue/Webpack project. I ran into this issue because my entry point was a Javascript file (`app.js`) and making it a Typescript file (`app.ts`) solved it.